# Why OpenCV 4.7.0 removed estimatePoseSingleMarkers()?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, augmented-reality, aruco, pose-estimation

From OpenCV 4.7.0 appears that **estimatePoseSingleMarkers()** not longer exists in favor to **SolvePnP()** for Pose Estimation as stated in OpenCV documentation https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html Is there any reason or I'm missing something?

I found that in documentation for 4.7.0 appears estimatePoseSingleMarkers() as deprecated https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/da/d58/deprecated.html#_deprecated000071

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been removed because `cv::solvePnP()` serves the same purpose.

The added benefit of `solvePnP()` is that you aren't limited to whatever coordinate system used to be "prescribed" by the aruco module's `estimatePoseSingleMarkers()` function.

You can choose to place the marker's origin in the center or on any of its corners. You can even choose to have Z point into or out of the marker, or to assign the axes entirely differently.